# What causes symbol names to be embedded in the compiled binary (not in debug info), causing bloat?

Tags: c++, templates, embedded, debug-symbols, name-mangling

The image for my embedded (ARM Cortex-M) firmware is significantly bloated from what looks like symbol names, some of which are very long due to C++ templates instantiated with lambda closures. The code is compiled with ARM GCC 10.1 with:

`-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g0`

I have made sure that there are no stray occurences of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or similar scattered around.

The strings are found using the `arm-none-eabi-strings` program, which basically just looks for byte sequences looking like strings. It is run on the binary image, which does not contain debug symbols.

What could be causing strings of type names to be embedded in the image? The code does make use of virtual methods, so vtables are generated. However, I had assumed that `-fno-rtti` would prevent the generation of type info structures.

EDIT: The compilation process is handled by CMake, but these are the commands run by CMake (with absolute paths removed for readability):

```
# compile
arm-none-eabi-g++
  -I<SDK-includes> 
  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=hard
  -Wall -Werror
  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
  -fno-rtti -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=3 -fno-exceptions
  -Os -DNDEBUG -g3 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0
  -fcoroutines -fno-use-cxa-atexit -std=c++2a -o main.cpp.obj -c main.cpp

# link
arm-none-eabi-g++
  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=hard  
  -Werror
  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
  -fno-rtti -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=3 -fno-exceptions
  -Os -DNDEBUG -g3
  --specs=nosys.specs -Tlinker-script.ld
  -static -Wl,--gc-sections,--entry,Reset_Handler
  -Wl,--start-group -lm -lc -lgcc -Wl,--end-group
  main.cpp.obj -o main.elf

# extract binary
arm-none-eabi-objcopy
  -O binary main.elf main.bin
```

I have tried with `-g0` as-well, but after `objcopy`, the debug symbols are stripped anyway.

The compiler is GCC 10.1:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q2-preview) 10.1.1 20200529 (release)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: try `-g0` option

Comment: That would aim at suppressing the debug symbols. These are already stripped. The strings I see on the other hand are found in the .text section; i.e. constant data, which could be used for printing at runtime - however, I don't have any code that would make use of those strings. In fact, `-g0` is already in place (edited the question to clarify that).

Comment: How are you creating the binary?  `objcopy -O binary ...` for example discards all symbol and relocation information.  Best to show a complete clean build log, copy and pasted , so we can see exactly how you are compiling, linking and generating the binary.  That is much simpler and far more informative that trying to "describe" what you are doing, and in this case omitting a great deal of necessary diagnostic information.

Comment: Show the entire compilation command, and give the exact version of our C++ compiler.